# Data import and default target schema empty list. (Mysql workbench 8)

Tags: sql, mysql

When I try to import a `.sql` file, then I select `import from self-contained file`, then I try to select a schema from the list - it's empty.

I tried to create a new schema on import but no effect.

Endless import.

What is this bug? How to fix?

Comment: double click on the sql file or choose open sql scripot and the run it

Comment: @nbk Holy moly, it's worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql files are only text

a double click on the file should open workbench with the file loaded

Else you can use `open sql script`

[image]

the rest is only running the script